# using capget syscall from Perl under docker with capsh --drop=cap_sys_admin

Tags: linux, docker, perl

I'm trying to use perl in a minimal environment (i.e. without Linux::Capabilities) to find out the current capability set. This seems to work fine with the following snippet:

```
require "syscall.ph";
my $hdrp=pack("Li",0x20080522,0);
my $datap=pack("LLLLLL", 0,0,0,0,0,0);
my $ret=syscall(&SYS_capget, $hdrp, $datap);
my ($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4, $v5, $v6) = unpack "LLLLLL", $datap;
print "foo: $ret $! $v1, $v2, $v3, $v4, $v5, $v6\n";
```

Running the above with sudo on my system returns `4294967295` and looking at bit 21 (from the right) I can see that CAP_SYS_ADMIN is set. Similarly, I can run the whole thing with `capsh --drop=cap_sys_admin` like this:

```
$ sudo capsh --drop=cap_sys_admin -- -c 'exec "$@"' exec perl -e 'require "syscall.ph"; my $hdrp=pack("Li",0x20080522,0); my $datap=pack("LLLLLL", 0,0,0,0,0,0);my $ret=syscall(&SYS_capget, $hdrp, $datap); my ($v1, $v2, $v3, $v4, $v5, $v6) = unpack "LLLLLL", $datap; print "foo: $ret $! $v1, $v2, $v3, $v4, $v5, $v6\n";'
```

This will print `4292870143` which (as expected) has bit 21 not set because we just dropped `CAP_SYS_ADMIN`.

The problems start, when I run above code in docker as part of our CI. Under docker, *both* of the invocations above will print `4294967295` and make it thus appear as if `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` was set even though it should've been disabled by `capsh --drop=cap_sys_admin`. To check whether maybe something was odd about `capsh --drop=cap_sys_admin` under docker, I ran `capsh --print` with and without `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` dropped and the results seem to make sense:

```sh
$ capsh --print
Current: =eip
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read
Ambient set =
Current IAB: cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,!%cap_sys_module,!%cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,!%cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,!%cap_mac_override,!%cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-ambient-raise: no (unlocked)
uid=0(root) euid=0(root)
gid=0(root)
groups=0(root)
Guessed mode: UNCERTAIN (0)
```

And in the following, `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` is missing or enabled (as expected):

```sh
$ capsh --drop=cap_sys_admin -- -c exec "$@" exec capsh --print
Current: =eip
Bounding set =cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read
Ambient set =
Current IAB: cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_dac_read_search,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_linux_immutable,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_broadcast,cap_net_admin,cap_net_raw,cap_ipc_lock,cap_ipc_owner,!%cap_sys_module,!%cap_sys_rawio,cap_sys_chroot,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_sys_pacct,!%cap_sys_admin,cap_sys_boot,cap_sys_nice,cap_sys_resource,!%cap_sys_time,cap_sys_tty_config,cap_mknod,cap_lease,cap_audit_write,cap_audit_control,cap_setfcap,!%cap_mac_override,!%cap_mac_admin,cap_syslog,cap_wake_alarm,cap_block_suspend,cap_audit_read
Securebits: 00/0x0/1'b0
 secure-noroot: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-suid-fixup: no (unlocked)
 secure-keep-caps: no (unlocked)
 secure-no-ambient-raise: no (unlocked)
uid=0(root) euid=0(root)
gid=0(root)
groups=0(root)
Guessed mode: UNCERTAIN (0)
```

So what is my Perl code doing wrong? It works fine without docker but under docker it doesn't seem to see the difference between being run with or without `capsh --drop=cap_sys_admin`. What am I missing?